# Validate input with regular expression for universal alphabets in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I have a [form validator by AntonLapshin](https://github.com/AntonLapshin/popup-validation) where I'm trying to validate a non-empty input field which can only take alphabets, space, - and '. The alphabets can be a-z, A-Z and europian letters æÆøØåÅöÖéÉèÈüÜ, etc. [See this for more details](http://www.port135.com/2017/01/31/how-to-allow-european-characters-in-text-fields-by-using-regular-expression/).

Here is what I am doing:

```
method  : function(input) {
    return input.value !== ''
        && input.value === /^[a-zA-Z'\- \u00c0-\u017e]+$/
}
```

Here, it should match: `Åløæ-Bond Mc'Cool`

But fail: `123-Bond Mc'C@o!`

When I run `^[a-zA-Z'\- \u00c0-\u017e]+$` in [regex tester](https://www.regextester.com/), It works absolutely fine, but in my script, it is not validating and throws an invalid input error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Would be helpful to have the error from your script

Comment: What error is coming from your script?

Comment: There's no syntax error in my script. It's just the regex pattern not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to use `RegExp`. You also need to do `return pattern.test(input)`

This will work :)

```js
var test1 = "Åløæ-Bond Mc'Cool";
var test2 = "123-Bond Mc'C@o!";

var pattern = new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z'\- \u00c0-\u017e]+$/);

function regextest(input) {
    return input !== '' && pattern.test(input)
}

console.log(regextest(test1))
console.log(regextest(test2))
```

Comment: Using `RegExp` is not necessary, but `pattern.test` is ;)

Comment: Really? @Zim Wow, I never realized that :) Learn something new every day ;) updated

Answer (score 1):

modify your function to test with regex

```js
var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z'\- \u00c0-\u017e]+$/

var method = function(input) {
  return input !== '' &&
    pattern.test(input)
}

//your sample strings
console.log(method("Åløæ-Bond Mc'Cool"))
console.log(method("123 - Bond Mc 'C@o!"))
```

Comment: Don't know how there are 2 upvotes on this answer.. it doesn't work for me @CodeMonk

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a simpler solution for my question:

```
method  : function(input) {
    return input.value !== '' && /^[a-zA-Z'\- \u00c0-\u017e]+$/.test(input.value)
}
```

The problem was, after the `&&` operator, I was checking for the input value (that’s wrong in regex check) instead of Boolean value.

This solution works perfectly and creates no confusion.

Comment: You’re right. I’m only referring to the readability referring to my own question